# How can I handle Message=The data type SqlDecimal is not supported. in Azure DWH v2

Tags: sql, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I'm facing difficulties solving the error message below received from the Azure datafactory v2 while tying to run a pipeline to copy a csv to a SQL table

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The data type SqlDecimal is not supported.,Source=,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Invervence Blob to SQL from csv",
    "details": []
}
```

What I've tried so far is changing the original .xslx file to a .CSV to eliminate possible formatting issues. In the mapping settings, when I delete the 'BEDRAG_2020' column from the copy task in the pipeline works fine, see snippet below.
[Snippet of data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tGOX.png)

Can someone help me troubleshooting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to self:

For unknown reasons the error appears in cases where the string value in another column exceeds the allocated varchar length. This affects the decimal type column in such way the Azure pipeline terminates. If someone knows some more details that rases this error please leave a comment.